# Raise a error message when price_unit is less than pricelist in odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo-9

```
@api.multi
    @api.onchange('price_unit')
    def price_unit_chnage(self):
        price = self.env['product.pricelist.item']
        prices = price.search([('pricelist_id', '=', self.order_id.pricelist_id.id), ('product_id', '=', self.product_id.id)])
        if prices:
            for x in self.browse(prices):
                if x.price_unit < x.order_id.pricelist_id.id:
                    raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('Unit price must be greater then fixed price'))
```

This is my .py code.

I am getting an error saying

> ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'product.pricelist.

Anyone out there who can help?

Comment: Is there a reason for comparing the unit price with the id from the pricelist?

Comment: yes.. price unit must be more then or equal to value set in pricelist.

Comment: you're not comparing with the price in the pricelist but the id in the pricelist. you should change the if condition to use the correct price.

(this won't solve the error but it's a different error in the code)

Comment: Soo what should be the solution..?? Can you please help me out..??

Comment: your method is on the sale.order model?